# ASP.NET web application Web.config staticContent error IIS server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, web-config, static-content

I have the following defined on my Web.config file so that it will serve json files.

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
```

This works fine when running the application with Visual Studio, but when using this project with IIS server it will make it not deliver any css or javascript files leaving html alone. Commenting out the lines fixes it.

Is that the wrong way of telling the server to accept json file requests? Otherwise, why does it create a conflict on IIS?